# Unverified app screen in google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am hosting some Web Applications in Google Cloud Platform using App Engine and those are for internal purpose only. One month ago I got a mail from Google Cloud Team, saying one of my apps needs verification. By based on their response I did some research and finally migrated all apps to the Organisation level as they mentioned in documentation (below link for reference). https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7394288#gsuite-app

But, yesterday also I got another notification regarding the same.

[image: Unverified App Notification]

May I ignore this notification, or are there any further steps I need to complete?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this other documentation page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865):

> If you're creating an internal web app for which [...] your project is
>   associated with a Cloud Organization that your users belong to, you
>   don't need to go through verification. **Internal users of your
>   application won't see the unverified app screen**.

If your application will only be used by internal users belonging to the same organization as where your project is located, you can ignore this message. It was probably triggered by the fact that your application is indeed not verified (although you do not need to do so).

So if that is the case, you will only need, as stated in the link you shared, to [create an Organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations) and then [migrate your existing project to that organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) (then make sure that the users who will be accessing the app belong to the same organization).